# I can't import card library in my Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I install Android Studio in my new Pc, I tried to start a new project but I couldn´t because I have this error when I try to compile some new library of Material Design as CardView or RecyclerView, I was reading about this problem and I tried to do everything, I installed all SDK, I change the library versions a lot times, but I cant resolve this =(.

This is the picture of my error:

[image: My Error]

Please, any help will be greatfully. I can´t program if I dont resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import with `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'` , this should work with API 22.

Click on `Sync now` in the warning on top of the code window.

If it doesn't work, try `Build -> Rebuild Project`. Seems that your gradle file doesn't refresh automatically

If it doesn't work check in the `SDK Manager` that you have install all the SDK pachages needed for those libraries and rebuild again.

Comment: Thanks, but the error persists, I can resolve change de targetSDKversion, but I would like resolve well the problem.

Comment: Import with `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'` , this should work with API 22

Comment: Where I can see the library? I was search this line "compile 'com..." to import my cardview, but I don´t find it.

Comment: Just change `recyclerview` for `cardview`

Answer (score 1):

just use
         `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'`

as the popup says the library you try to import doesn't work with android version 22

and to make sure you don't import outdated libraries like this import them that way.

1-[image]

2-[image]

3-[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add card view lib from     Open module settings-> app ->  dependencies-> +  -> Library dependency. It will be perfect . this happens you have updated version 22 installed in your sdk and not the previous version 21   .
or use 
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'